# ¿Como crear opciones a un select por Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, javascript-objeto

He estado trabajando en un formulario donde quiero añadir opciones por Javascript pero ya he visto varios tutoriales y ejemplos y ninguno me funciona. Ya probé con 2 códigos distintos y ninguno me funcionó:

###### Codigo 1:

```
function Country(form) {
  let select = form.country.options;
  let combo = select;
  combo.length = null;
  let paisesLista = ["USA","Mexico","Guatemala","El Salvador","Costa Rica", "Brasil","Ecuador","Perú","Argentina","Colombia"];

  if (select[0].selected == true) {
    combo[0] = new Option(0, paisesLista[0], ' ', ' ');
    combo[0].select;
  }
}
```

###### Codigo 2:

```
function Country(form) {
  let seleccion = form.country.select;
  seleccion.length = null;
  let construction = document.createElement('option');
  let paisesLista = ["USA","Mexico","Guatemala","El Salvador","Costa Rica", "Brasil","Ecuador","Perú","Argentina","Colombia"];
  if (seleccion[0].select == true) {
    seleccion[0] = construction(paisesLista[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El siguiente es un código básico de insersión de opciones al select:

```js
function agregarOpcion() {
  var select = document.getElementsByName("test")[0];

  var option = document.createElement('OPTION');
  option.innerHTML = "3";
  option.value = "3";
  
  select.options.add(option);
}
```

```html
<select name="test">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
</select>

<button onClick="agregarOpcion()">agregar opcion</button>
```

Aquí con la lista de paises:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
  var select = document.getElementsByName("test")[0];
  let paisesLista = ["USA","Mexico","Guatemala","El Salvador","Costa Rica", "Brasil","Ecuador","Perú","Argentina","Colombia"];
  
  for (var i of paisesLista) {
      var option = document.createElement('OPTION');
      option.innerHTML = i;
      option.value = i;

      select.options.add(option);
  }
});
```

```html
<select name="test"></select>
```